# How to subset a data.table object based on passed parameter within a function?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm having trouble figuring out how to subset a data.table in R within a function. My code is below and uses the iris dataset for simplicity. My goal is to iterate through a dataset, and perform many different functions within each subgroup, and store all the resulting values in a single dataset representing that subgroup. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
  fx <- function(data, col_var){
  for(i in 0:nrow(distinct(data[,..col_var]))){
    if(i == 0){
      # do one thing
    }
    else if(i > 0){
      group <- data %>% distinct('col_var')
      group_dt <- data['col_var' == group[1],]
      print(group_dt)
    }
  }
}

library('tidyverse')
library('data.table')
data(iris)
data <- data.table(iris)
fx(data, 'Species')
```

Unfortunately, all of my efforts so far either result in a subset of the data that has no rows, or an error message like one of the below:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(data, "col_var" == group[1], ) : 
i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please let datatable-help know if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #657.
```

Comment: I don't understand this code. 1 - You are practically trying to run operations by group, this is what the `by` argument for. Hence there is absolutely no need in all these `distinct` and `for` loops calls. 2- you are trying to subset a data.table using solely a tydiverse code. It's like to running R script using a Python code- what's the point really? In otehr words, your function could be something like  `fx <- function(data, col_var) data[, if(.N == 1) {do one thing} else {do something else}, by = col_var]`

Comment: If you are to use `data.table` you should forget about `tidyverse` and do every thing the data.table way: https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf. You should also try not to use `for` loops in data analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I'm pretty new to using data.tables and tidyverse and just trying to figure out some new skills. Coming from a SAS background, it's difficult to un-learn iterative data processing, so it's taking some time to figure out writing functions in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### data.table way

In most cases you can do everything in `data.table` without any iteration controls (`for` or `lapply`)

```
dt <- data.table(iris)
group.by.name <- "Species"
res <- dt[, .(count = .N), by = group.by.name]
```

### split-transform-rbind strategy:

If you need to do a complex transformations over `data.table`, you can split-transform-rbind data like this:

```
library('data.table')
dt <- data.table(iris)
group.by.name <- "Species"
res <- lapply(split(dt, by = group.by.name), function(data) {
  data[, .(count = .N)]
})
res <- rbindlist(res, idcol = group.by.name)
```

You have a trade of between readability and speed. 
With `mcapply` you might event gain speed on larger instances.

Usually you will be able to move complex logic into vector functions and do it data.table way without loosing readability.